# Is it possible to add a gradle task, upon installation, to grant all needed permissions?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, permissions, adb

### Background

Starting from Android 6, each time you install an app, you need to grant its permissions during runtime.

### The problem

This can become really annoying when running apps from the IDE, as you need to re-grant the permissions every time you want to try out the app (if it wasn't installed), which is tedious operation, especially if you have multiple permissions.

Of course, it's important to test the app this way too, because that's how users will use the app, but starting from certain point at time, it's not needed, because you already handled it fine

### What I've tried

Only thing I've found is how to create a new gradle task for this ([**here**](https://afterecho.uk/blog/granting-marshmallow-permissions-for-testing-flavoured-builds.html)), but this doesn't work together with the installation. Instead, I need to run it separately, but for this I can just use a batch file anyway, using adb commands.

Another thing I've found ([**here**](https://afterecho.uk/blog/granting-marshmallow-permissions-for-testing-flavoured-builds.html#comment-3119867512)) is something that does it, but also re-install (meaning you install the app two times instead of once, each time you want to do it) the app before launching it for some reason, so this is not a good solution.

### The question

Is there a way that upon installation of the app via the IDE, all permissions will be auto-granted?